# Cassandra DSE Spark scala Application maven build error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'am trying to create a spark application to run spark sql query from Cassandra DSE, but I'am unable to build my application using maven. Attaching below my code and pom.xml.

```
package com.spark
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object controller {
def main(args : Array[String]){
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("testing").
set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.0.113").
set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
val sqlc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
print(sqlc.sql("select * from test.test limit 10).collect().toList)"));
 }
}
```

POM.xml is as follows :-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
 < modelVersion >4.0.0< /modelVersion>

< groupId>com.spark< /groupId>
<artifactId>Controller</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
        <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- for fatjar -->
        <plugin>
            <!-- <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.4</version> -->
            <!-- <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>src.main.resources.assemblies</groupId> 
                <artifactId>myassembly</artifactId> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency> 
                </dependencies> -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- <finalName>test</finalName> -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>src.main.com.spark.Controller</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src\main\resources\assemblies\myassembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors> -->
                <!-- <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                         <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                    <artifactId> maven-scala-plugin                                     </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange> [2.15.2,)                                        </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

On Clean install it gives following error :  `- 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) on project Controller: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: invalid CEN header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you have corrupted jars in the `~/.m2/repository/` folder. You need to remove either full directory, or only dependencies that you currently using...

Update after getting the getting new error message: The different versions of Scala are used in project - `spark-core` is built with 2.10, while `spark-sql` & cassandra connector are on 2.11.

Comment: Hi Alex, I googled and initial result was this so I manually tried by removing entire repository and in second case tried binding jar files by downloading and keeping in ~/.m2/repository , both ways my code failed . Need some more feedback if I can do anything else . Thanks

Comment: Can you try to track what jar is corrupt? Something like this command: https://gist.github.com/alexott/affbf25b69a142cc3f71af278509e31e - I was need to use gist because of back quotes, etc.

Comment: Hi Alex,There is version issue it works for thsi

    val lRDD = sc.cassandraTable("test", "test")
    lRDD.collect.foreach(println)

but gives an error for -

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly in package scala.annotation which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.test Unknown Scala Problem

Comment: see updated answer - you're mixing up Scala versions in the same project

Comment: Hi Alex, 

Your advice worked. I had to do some R&D to check version compatibility, but your input helped a lot and issue resolved.  Thanks for your time. I'am accepting your answer. cheers, Aditya Jain